# Java Lang Null Pointer Exception, but I don't understand why?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I get a Java Lang Null Pointer Exception at this code:

```
for (int i = 0; i<fragen.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x<dbfragen.size(); x++)
        {
            if(i == dbfragen.get(x).getFrageNR())
            {
                if(fragen.get(i).getTyp() == 1)
                {
```

It happens in the last if statement.
I used the Log file:
fragen.size() is 30
and it crashes at i = 1

this makes no sense to me :O

Please help ;)

Comment: It should tell you the exact line. `dbfragen` is null or the object returned by `dbfragen.get(x)` or `fragen.get(i)` should be null.

Comment: try to print fragen.get(i) , then fragen.get(i).getTyp() before your if condition , see which one throws exception

Comment: It tells me it's in line 49 (this is fragen.get(i).getTyp() ==1)

But it works the first time, when i is 0, but not the second time, when it is 1

Comment: Why don't you just show your full code?

Comment: The full code has more than 1000 lines

Comment: When I add the following before the last if statement:

Frage f = fragen.get(i);
int typ = f.getTyp();

Then the error is at int typ = f.getTyp();

Does that mean, that getTyp() returns null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A collection can have 30 nulls in it.  I suspect the first element is not null so it it fine but the second element index:1 is null.

BTW I suggest caching the lookup.

```
for (int i = 0; i<fragen.size(); i++) {
    MyType fragenI = fragen.get(i);
    if (fragenI == null) {
       // do something
       continue;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.
You are right, there are 29 nulls in it.

Now i have to find out why...